# Crossfilter dimension filtering

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm working on dc.js charts. I have setup the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hv6dnr18/11/).

I have the data below:

```
var data = [
  {"state": "A","value": 100,"volume": 10,"id": 4,"date": "10/1/2017","category": "H","channel": "CRM"},
  {"state": "B","value": 50,"volume": 10,"id": 2,"date": "8/1/2017","category": "A","channel": "CRM"},
  {"state": "A","value": 250,"volume": 5,"id": 4,"date": "10/1/2017","category": "H","channel": "CRM"},
  {"state": "A","value": 40,"volume": 4,"id": 3,"date": "9/1/2017","category": "A","channel": "Sales"},
  {"state": "C","value": 10,"volume": 1,"id": 5,"date": "11/1/2017","category": "A","channel": "Sales"},
  {"state": "B","value": 10,"volume": 1,"id": 2,"date": "8/1/2017","category": "H","channel": "CRM"},
  {"state": "D","value": 150,"volume": 3,"id": 1,"date": "7/1/2017","category": "A","channel": "Sales"},
  {"state": "D","value": 100,"volume": 5,"id": 1,"date": "7/1/2017","category": "H","channel": "Sales"},
  {"state": "C","value": 50,"volume": 1,"id": 5,"date": "11/1/2017","category": "H","channel": "Sales"}
]
```

I have four dimensions (state, category, channel, id) and all are grouped by value.

I need to know if I can filter the dimension such that if I set the range 60, the charts should show all the ids whose value total is greater than 60.

For example it the states pie chart should show only the slices where the value is greater than 60, i.e. A and D only.

Comment: I edited your question slightly because you were talking about "greater than or equal to 60" but for your example to work, you had to mean "greater than 60". Of course it only changes the answer slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By itself, crossfilter won't filter by value. If you think about it, it would be pretty complicated to filter the data set by the rows by the ones that will reduce to a certain value, before it's done the reduction.

But I think you're not looking for filtering so much as just not showing the slices that are too small. You can do that using a ["fake group"](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups). This is a postprocessing step which won't change what data is included in the crossfilter filters, just what items you choose to display.

This one is very similar to the "remove empty bins" fake group. But instead of looking for the value 0, we'll look for a minimum value.

```
function remove_small_bins(source_group, lower_bound) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                return d.value > lower_bound;
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Applying it to your example (the fiddle data is slightly different from the data shown above), first we need to look at `d.value.orderValue instead of just`d.value`:

```
function remove_small_bins(source_group, lower_bound) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                return d.value.orderValue > lower_bound;
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Apply the fake group like this:

```
var stateGroup = stateDim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);
var stateGroupNoSmalls = remove_small_bins(stateGroup, 60);
// ...
stateChart
  .group(stateGroupNoSmalls)
```

Fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/cyjztajv/2/

Comment: thanks for the answer.But when I put slicecap on those pieCharts , why does it show NaN....https://jsfiddle.net/cyjztajv/3/

Comment: That has nothing to do with this question - it also happens without `remove_small_bins` enabled. You are pulling custom fields from the reduced data in your `label` function, and the default [othersGrouper](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.capMixin.html#othersGrouper__anchor) doesn't know how to populate those fields. Please ask another question if you can't figure out how to write a custom `othersGrouper` for this.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I know it happens without `remove_small_bins` also.I was just asking for your guidance on how to tackle that othersGrouper issue.

Comment: Stack Overflow works best when there is a specific question and a specific answer. Please give `othersGrouper` a try, and if you can't figure it out, start another question. That way when people are searching for information about getting the labels right for the others slice, they'll find a clear question about it, rather than something buried in the comments.